# C getchar error

Tags: c, eof, getchar

I wrote the most innocuous C program but I can't get the expected result. I hope you can tell where my error is.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int c, var4;
    double var1,var2,var3;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {

        while (c != ':') {
            putchar(c);
            c = getchar();
        }
        //scanf("%d/%d/%d",&mm,&dd,&yy);
        //scanf("%lf%lf%lf%d",&var1,&var2,&var3,&var4);  
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and I'm using this file for input(command line redirection)

> Name1 - Code1:
>   04/03/2011  4.5  5.6  9.8 145
>   04/03/2011  6.5  4.6  9.9 185
>   Name2 - Code2:
>   05/03/2011  4.5  5.6  9.8 135
>   05/03/2011  6.5  4.6  9.9 165

The error appears during `while` loop (I tried `printf` instead of `putchar` and it prints `-1` endlessly and seems to never reach `EOF`)

I thinks that's all, I thank your help in advance.

Comment: What error are you getting?  I assume you're expecting to see `Name1 - Code1`?  Have you tried `char c;`?

Comment: thanks everyone and sorry, It was kind of silly question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting one character, then going into the inner loop — which checks for `':'`, but not for `EOF`.  So, unless the file ends with  `:` (so that it will be seen by the outer loop), the inner loop will spin forever when it hits `EOF`.

Answer (score 1):

The inner loop doesn't stop at EOF.

You're getting an error from getchar **(EOF == -1)** because thee file is finished. That's what it's printing endlessly.

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking for EOF inside your inner getchar loop, therefore allowing it to continuously read EOF (-1) and printing that out.

I don't know what your expected result is so I cannot help you there.